# Geocoder.google returning None values in Python

Tags: python, r, google-geocoder, reverse-geocoding

I am trying to use the geocoder.google to find zipcodes from the lat, long values. It keeps returning `None` value.

INPUT

```
a = gc.google([33.573256, -111.906344], method='reverse')
print a.postal
print a.address
```

OUTPUT

```
None
None
```

Can someone also tell me an easier way for converting Lat/long to zipcodes in python (preferably) or R. I have a csv file with about 58,000 rows. I want to find associated zipcodes to all these Lat,Lon values

Comment: FYI that is going to cost you $28 to use the google api for that many addresses.

Comment: @AndyW Can you direct me to an alternative solution?

Answer (score 3):

From the Geopy github link

https://github.com/geopy/geopy

I used one of the examples to come up with a possible solution for you

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()
loc = geolocator.reverse("33.573256, -111.906344")
print(loc.address)

8006, East del Timbre Drive, Scottsdale, Maricopa County, Arizona, 85258, United States of America
```

This doesn't address the problem with the code you already have but it sounds like you are looking for any solution that works.

Comment: Does it limit me to only 'n' number of addresses per day? From @Andy's comment above I am assuming that all the geocoding libraries which might be using Google API will not let me query for 58000 addresses.

Comment: I don't know unfortunately.  They probably have some guidelines on this on their webpage.

Comment: This example uses Nominatim - which is not google - so I don't know there usage rates. See http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/21390/751 for advice about batch geocoding. Census has zip code areas, it is a simple task in a desktop GIS program.